# RuntimeError: output with shape [1, 512, 512] doesn't match the broadcast shape [3, 512, 512]

Tags: python, torch, torchvision

I want to train model to semantic segmentation.

Input images shape (512, 512).
Target masks shape (512, 512, 3)

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, datasets, models

class SimDataset(Dataset):
  def __init__(self, input_images_list, target_masks_list, transform=None):
    self.input_images = input_images_list
    self.target_masks = target_masks_list
    self.transform = transform

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.input_images)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
    image = self.input_images[idx]
    mask = self.target_masks[idx]
    if self.transform:
      image = self.transform(image)

    return [image, mask]

trans = transforms.Compose([
  transforms.ToTensor(),
  transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]) # imagenet
])


train_set = SimDataset(train_image_data_list, train_target_image_list, transform = trans)
val_set = SimDataset(val_image_data_list, val_target_image_list, transform = trans)

image_datasets = {'train': train_set, 'val': val_set}

batch_size = 3

dataloaders = {
  'train': DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0),
  'val': DataLoader(val_set, batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=0)
}

inputs, masks = next(iter(dataloaders['train']))
```

I got this error

RuntimeError: output with shape [1, 512, 512] doesn't match the broadcast shape [3, 512, 512]

How to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct masks shape? Usually masks are of shape (h, w, 1) or (h, w)

Comment: Yes. it is generated, firstly it generate sample image (512, 512) and after added RGB mask on that image and create target (512, 512, 3).